# Confusion on wording for an exercise (Groups/Abstract Algebra)

Tags: group-theory

I am having trouble understanding an exercise in a book that I am reading. The exercise is:

"Let G be a finite abelian group. If G has at most m elements, of order dividing m for each divisor of (G:1), show G is cyclic."

What is (G:1)? I have never seen this notation before.

I have tried looking this up, but have only gotten results about G1 horses. (Google gets rid of the parens and the semicolon when searching). Also, the book is on fields and assumes the reader has knowledge of what this (G:1) is.

Thank you!

Comment: It's just the order of $G$ itself. Restated, the problem is this: 
$$$$
Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of order $n$. Suppose $G$ is such that, for every positive integer divisor $m$ of $n$, $G$ has at most $m$ elements of order $m$. Prove that $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: Oh. Is there a reason for the 1? I'm used to seeing it as |G| and ord(G).

Comment: If $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup, the notation $[G:H]$ (read as "the index of $H$in $G$") is the cardinality of the set of cosets of $H$ in $G$. In this context, $G:1$ means $[G:\{ 1 \}]$, which is just the order of $G$.

Comment: Corrected restatement:
$$$$
Let G be a finite abelian group of order n. Suppose G is such that, for every positive integer divisor m of n, G has at most m elements of order _dividing_ m. Prove that G is cyclic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a finite group $G$ with subgroup $H$, the notation $(G:H)$ is basically $|G|/|H|$.  So, when $H$ is the trivial group $\{1\}$ (often shortened just to $1$), $(G:H) = |G|/|H| = |G|/1=|G|$.

Seems silly for the book to use the heavy-handed $(G:1)$ for something as simple as $|G|$, but here we are.

$(G:H)$ is defined in complete generality as a possibly-infinite cardinal, so that it may be used with infinite groups.  But in the finite case it's as simple as what I wrote above.